# Totally computable least real upper bounds for bounded recursive sets of totally computable real numbers?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory

A recursive set $Y$ is a set with a characteristic total computable function $\chi_Y$ so that $\chi_Y(n)=0$ iff $n\in Y$ and $\chi_Y(n)=1$ iff $n\notin Y$. Let a $recursive \ condition$ be one which defines a recursive set. Let a recursive condition $Q(n)$ for "is a rational number" be given. A totally computable real number is here taken as a natural number $\ulcorner M\urcorner$ which encodes a Turing machine M and such that for some recursive condition $A(x)$, $\ulcorner M\urcorner$ is the least natural number $(U(\mu zT(\ulcorner M\urcorner,z,x))=0\leftrightarrow Q(x)\wedge A(x))\wedge (U(\mu zT(\ulcorner M\urcorner,z,x))=1\leftrightarrow\lnot (Q(x)\wedge A(x))) $; it is presupposed that $Q(x)\wedge A(x)$ amounts to a Dedekind cut. For instance, the Turing Machine $g$ given by  $(U(\mu zT(\ulcorner g\urcorner,z,x))=0\leftrightarrow Q(x)\wedge x<_\mathbf{Q}2\cdot_\mathbf{q}x)\wedge 
(U(\mu zT(\ulcorner g\urcorner,z,x))=1\leftrightarrow\lnot (Q(x)\wedge x<_\mathbf{Q}2\cdot_\mathbf{q}x)) $

prints $0$ if it is given the input of a natural number $x$ fulfilling the recursive condition $Q(x)\wedge x<_\mathbf{Q}2\cdot_\mathbf{q}x$ and prints $1$ if it is given a natural number $x$ fulfilling the recursive condition $\lnot (Q(x)\wedge x<_\mathbf{Q}2\cdot_\mathbf{q}x)$ as input.

It is known by a result of Specker that bounded computable sets of computable real numbers do not always have a computable real number  as a least upper bound. Is the situation different for totally computable real numbers as here so that recursive sets of totally computable real numbers with an upper bound have a least upper bound which is totally computable?

Comment: If you insist that $M$ be the least number with the given property, then it seems that any recursive set of totally computable real numbers must be finite, since given an infinite such set $S$, we can use the recursion theorem to build a TM with index $N$ that finds the least $M \in S$ greater than $N$, and then copies the TM with index $M$, contradicting the minimality of $M$.

Comment: @DenisHirschfeldt When I was first learning this stuff, that was the first application of the recursion theorem that *really* surprised me.

Comment: @DenisHirschfeldt It is $\ulcorner M\urcorner$ which is taken as a natural number in a part of my question.

Comment: @DenisHirschfeldt I do not understand this. Can one get your suggested use of the recursion theorem without an essential use of properly partial recursive functions somewhat alien to totally computable real numbers as suggested here? More precisely, would such a Turing machine as you suggest be a total computable function defining a recursive set?

Comment: Yes, if $S$ is an infinite recursive set of totally computable real numbers then the Turing machine coded by $N$ by definition computes exactly the same function as the one coded by $M$, and hence this is indeed a total computable function defining a recursive set. (Sorry, I've been using $M$ to mean the same thing as $\ulcorner M \urcorner$.)

Comment: Why would the fact that a TM with index $\ulcorner N\urcorner$ copying a TM with index $\ulcorner M\urcorner\in S$  contradict the assumption that $\ulcorner M\urcorner$ is the least number as in my definition?

Comment: Because $\ulcorner M \urcorner$ is chosen so that $\ulcorner M \urcorner > \ulcorner N \urcorner$.

Comment: I would have to see this more elaborated to understand.

Comment: Here's a more general version: Let $\Phi_e$ be the Turing machine with index $e$. Say that a natural number $e$ is a minimal index if there is no $i<e$ such that $\Phi_i$ computes the same function as $\Phi_e$. Then every computable set of minimal indices is finite. Here's the proof: Suppose $S$ is an infinite computable set of minimal indices. By the recursion theorem, there is a natural number $i$ such that $\Phi_i$ acts as follows: Let $e$ be the least number greater than $i$ in $S$. Then $\Phi_i(n)=\Phi_e(n)$ for all $n$. The existence of $i$ contradicts the minimality of $e$.

Comment: To clarify the role of the recursion theorem in Denis' argument: suppose $S$ were an infinite computable set of minimal indices. Then (exercise) there is a total computable $f$ such that for all $i$, $f(i)$ is the least element of $S$ greater than $i$. Now apply the recursion theorem to $f$; we get a $c$ such that $\Phi_c\cong \Phi_{f(c)}$. OK, but then we know two things: (1) $f(c)$ is in $S$, and (2) $f(c)>c$. But this gives us a contradiction: each element of $S$ must be a minimal index, but $f(c)$ isn't since $c$ is a *smaller* index for the same partial computable function.