# Does Bounded Arithmetic, $I\Delta_0$, prove the Recursion Theorem?

Tags: lo.logic, computability-theory, bounded-arithmetic

Compare my question [Does Robinson Arithmetic already entail the Recursion Theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/267910/does-robinson-arithmetic-already-entail-the-recursion-theorem). I would find it desirable and interesting if $I\Delta_0$ could be extended with a comprehension principle CP stating the existence of $\lceil x|A(x)\rceil = \mu w\forall x((U(\mu zT(w,z,x))=0\leftrightarrow A(x))\wedge (U(\mu zT(w,z,x))=1\leftrightarrow\lnot A(x))) $ whenever A(x) is 
a recursive open sentence where x is free. $\mu x\alpha(x)$ is the least x so that $\alpha(x)$. $T$ and $U$ are as with Kleene. $\lceil x|A(x) \rceil$ on the left hand side is a natural number, but is also intended to represent the recursive set of natural numbers x such that $A(x)$. For instance, $\lceil x|x=x \rceil$ is a natural number, but also represents all natural numbers; we write $x\eta y$ for $U(\mu zT(y,z,x))=0$, and so have $\forall x (x\eta \lceil x|x=x \rceil$).

However, $I\Delta_0$ cannot be extended with CP if $I\Delta_0$ proves the Recursion Theorem. For the last point, confer the comment section of my question [Totally computable least real upper bounds for bounded recursive sets of totally computable real numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265549/totally-computable-least-real-upper-bounds-for-bounded-recursive-sets-of-totally)

Comment: The *least* $w$? That sounds like you want the Recursion theorem to give you the least fixed point, and that can't possibly work.

Comment: Actually, come to thinkof it, what does your formula even stand for? You've got a set on one side and a number on the other.

Comment: The set notation here is arguably uncalled for. Nevertheless, the idea is that the number on the left side ({xA(x)}) represents the set of numbers x which are A.

Comment: I specifically do not want the recursion theorem, but I do presuppose the Normal Form theorem. The outermost \textit{least} is part of the extension of $I\Delta_0$ with the new comprehension principle. Cfr. my former question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/265549/totally-computable-least-real-upper-bounds-for-bounded-recursive-sets-of-totally

Comment: Well, I think it would be nice if you explained the notation a bit in your question. I undestand what's on the left-hand side, but on the right hand side you seem to be asking for a number, namely the least $w$ such that ...

Comment: Do you think I should use different brackets, as in [x|A]?

Comment: On the right hand side I use Kleene's notation as in the Normal Form theorem.

Comment: Could we please stop the obfuscation here? Isn't $\mu x . P(x)$ just "the least $x$ such that $P(x)$ holds"?

Comment: It is. I do not understand what you take to be obfuscation. The T and U are as with Kleene.

Comment: I take it as obfuscation that you do not answer directly the question about what $\mu x . P(x)$ stands for. I think your question is very interesting and that this discussion is completely derailing it. Just pretty please explain the notation, even if you thin it's standard.

Comment: Also, if you could, please keep the diffferences between "set", "function" and "expression with a free variable". I suspect, but cannot tell for sure, that you are perhaps saying something about a function $A$ which is computed by getting a minimal $w$ (which depends on $x$). But I don't really want to guess all of this, I'd rather just read it.

Comment: I amplified to explain syntax, and hope it is now becoming clearer.

Comment: Thank you very much. I really do not want to be a pest, but let me ask whether "$[x \mid A(x)]$ on the left hand side is a natural number, but is also intended to represent the recursive set of natural numbers $x$ such that $A(x)$" is your way of saying "$[x|A(x)]$ is the least (code of) Turing machine that computes the characteristic function of $A(x)$", since that is what the left-hand side means (provided I squint and see the left-hand side as a function of $x$, when in reality $x$ is just a free variable on the left-hand side). Is it ok if I work with that?

Comment: You are not being a pest, and I am honoured by your interest. x is not a free variable in $\lceil x|A(x) \rceil$. Yes, I believe it is correct to say that $\lceil x|A(x) \rceil$ can be taken as the least code of a Turing machine  which computes the characteristic function of $A(x)$.

Comment: Excellent, now I can think of ways of abusing $[x \mid A(x)]$. Just one last question. Since we're in $I\Delta_0$, details matter. Do you imagine $[x \mid A(x)]$ to be a term-former, so that I can write things like $2 + [x \mid A(x)] > 7$, or woudl the comprehension schema really be expressed in first-order logic in the form "there exists $w$ such that ..." where "..." explains what $w$ is (and mentions $A$)? Because then we can run induction on such a schema, but with a term former we can.

Comment: I take $\lceil x:A(x) \rceil$ to be a term former, and I intend that $\ID_0+CP$ allows bounded induction on formulas that include these novel CP-terms. Your last sentence in your last message is unclear.